# How to call the table values through function

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I want to write a function or sub procedure for calling the table values

I have n number of textbox, each textbox i want to populate different values, i dont want to write repeated code for each textbox leave event, instead of that i can call function or sub procedure on each textbox leave event. Each textbox values is different.

Which is the best suggestion..?  How to do it.

Can any one help me and provide some piece of code.

Comment: Please, add your more clarification with code where you want ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what table? data table or datagridvew?

here a sample if it datagridview:

```
Function getValueFromDG(ByVal colIndex As Integer, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal dg As DataGridView) As String

return dg.Item(ColIndex, rowIndex).ToString


End Function
```

Datatable :

```
Function getValueFromDT(ByVal colIndex As Integer, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal dt As DataTable) 
 dg.Item(ColIndex, rowIndex) As String

 return myDataTable.Rows.Item(rowIndex).Item(colIndex ).ToString()

End Function
```

after that you can call that on you textbox event :

```
tb1.Text = getValueFromDG(0,0,myDG)  
tb2.Text = getValueFromDG(0,2,myDG)
```

Thats just a basic, you can improvise that.

Sorry if it's not helping.

Comment: Instead of row, can i call the items because i have only one row from the table.  How to do that...

Comment: the table format is contain row & col, no matter how much it is. you still need to set the row value (if it's just one column, so you need 0 as parameter). that's the rule :-) cmiw